# Photoshop: How to highlight object corner giving raised effect that is visible irrespective of background color?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want give this effect on corners that looks raised instead of flat on both dark and light colored objects like below

[image] 
[image]

**I tried using Bevel & Emboss effect:**

[image]

As you can see below, light background color gets raised effect with above settings
[image]

but nothing seems to visible like that on dark background color object corners and it looks flat.
[image]

Changing Altitude and Angle values shows raised effect on dark color but is not visible on light color. Played a lot many times with values but cannot get desired results. Am I missing something?

Please tell how can I get the raised effect visible on dark and light colored background object corners?

Comment: Set the effect to difference.

Comment: Welcome to **GDSE** - glad to have you here! Please look around [tour] to get a sense of who we are as a community, and what we're about. Look at [ask] and [answer] questions, to learn how to frame acceptable queries and what to expect of replies and answers; please also look at [help/behavior] to understand our community's internal behavioural expectations. So far, great start with a solid question, clear demonstration of what you've tried, and what your stopping issue is - again, welcome!

Comment: @13ruce where to select ?

Comment: Google "How to change blend mode in Photoshop."

Comment: @13ruce got it thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume your structure is like this:

[image]

You have a camera lens or some other interesting part surrounded by a beveled frame. The interesting part is in my image only dark grey, but I call it Mid part, the bevel area is lighter grey. You want to color the bevel as described in the question, but Mid part must stay as is.

Bevel & Emboss should do it. Here's a test of it:

[image]

At first we have BW test background layer, then we have two copies of the problematic shape. One copy has the beveled area and Mid part (= all), the other copy is the Mid part only. You need it because beveling easily affect to the whole shape. Delete the bevel area with a selection or set a layer mask to get the Mid part only.

Apply Bevel & Emboss to the whole shape layer. Find rich enough shading to make the bevel different than both possible backgrounds. I made my own bumpy bevel curve. It unfortunately lightens the Mid part, but we have a copy:

[image]

Place the Mid part only version to cover the affected Mid part. Test the looks on both background colors:

[image]

ADD: One long time member suggested that you actually want the phone body to be shaded. He has quite often written something that should be noted. So, here's a single Bevel&Emboss setting for both black and white phone bodies:

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP wanted to know how to replicate the shadows/highlights on the rounded edges of the black phone.

Comment: @Joonas  his own attempts have the phone body as the background.

Comment: I don't know man, he shows 2 original pictures with a white and a black phone and then 2 of his own attempts with the white phone showing a clearly different edge shadow and the black phone without any kinda highlight on the phone edge and he says `"but nothing seems to visible like that on dark background color object corners and it looks flat"`.

Comment: @Joonas It's possible that you are right. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to play with the HIghLight Mode and Shadow Mode.

The highlight mode is not needed after some tests.

I put a lighter color in the Shadow Mode and set it to Screen adjusting its opacity(The normal mode will work fine too).

See the image below:

[image]

Comment: Will the bottom settings work for both colours?